# How to change mouseenter with onclick in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, mouseover

I have this small script that allow me to show entries when user go with the mouse on a date in a calendar.
I would like to change this to set it at onclick function but I have no idea about how to do that:

This is the portion of code:

```
// Customisation Variables
                /** The CSS class which will be assigned to the Event Calendar */
                calendarClass: 'hasEventCalendar',
                /** The CSS class which will be assigned to day when the day contains a entry */
                dayEventClass: 'ui-state-active hasEvent',
                /** The standard options to send to the datepicker */
                datepickerOptions: {
                    firstDay: 1 /* Monday */
                },
                /** Whether or not to disable the datepicker date selection click */
                disableClick: true,
                /**
                 * The domEvents option contains all the events which you would like to assign to a $day
                 *
                 * It will send the following arguments back to you:
                 * - domEvent
                 * - details
                 *
                 * The details of the details argument contains the following:
                 * - {Number} year
                 * - {Number} month
                 * - {Number} day
                 * - {String} date
                 * - {Array} dayEntries
                 * - {Array} monthEntries
                 * - {Element} datepicker
                 */
                domEvents: {
                    mouseenter: function(domEvent, details) {
                        // Prepare
                        var $day = $(this),
                            dayEntries = details.dayEntries;
                        // Output
                        $.each(dayEntries,function(i,entry){
                            $eventsInfo.append(
                                '<p>'+
                                    '<strong>'+entry.title+'</strong> <br/>'+
                                    '<em>'+entry.start.toLocaleDateString()+'</em>'+
                                    '<br>'+entry.text+''+
                                '</p>'
                            );
                        });
                    },
                    mouseleave: function(domEvent, details) {
                        // Clear
                        $eventsInfo.empty();
                    }
                }
```

How can I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `mouseenter` attribute of `domEvents` to `onclick`, like so:

```
// Customisation Variables
                /** The CSS class which will be assigned to the Event Calendar */
                calendarClass: 'hasEventCalendar',
                /** The CSS class which will be assigned to day when the day contains a entry */
                dayEventClass: 'ui-state-active hasEvent',
                /** The standard options to send to the datepicker */
                datepickerOptions: {
                    firstDay: 1 /* Monday */
                },
                /** Whether or not to disable the datepicker date selection click */
                disableClick: true,
                /**
                 * The domEvents option contains all the events which you would like to assign to a $day
                 *
                 * It will send the following arguments back to you:
                 * - domEvent
                 * - details
                 *
                 * The details of the details argument contains the following:
                 * - {Number} year
                 * - {Number} month
                 * - {Number} day
                 * - {String} date
                 * - {Array} dayEntries
                 * - {Array} monthEntries
                 * - {Element} datepicker
                 */
                domEvents: {
                    onclick: function(domEvent, details) {
                        // Prepare
                        var $day = $(this),
                            dayEntries = details.dayEntries;
                        // Output
                        $.each(dayEntries,function(i,entry){
                            $eventsInfo.append(
                                '<p>'+
                                    '<strong>'+entry.title+'</strong> <br/>'+
                                    '<em>'+entry.start.toLocaleDateString()+'</em>'+
                                    '<br>'+entry.text+''+
                                '</p>'
                            );
                        });
                    },
                    mouseleave: function(domEvent, details) {
                        // Clear
                        $eventsInfo.empty();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That means you have other issues with your script. The code I provided should work.